# How to match a cyclically repeating sequence?

Tags: pattern-matching

I have run across several times recently where I must match a sequence that is cyclically repeating. For example, with the sequence,

```
Sequence[a, b, c]
```

how would I write a pattern that matched against

```
a
a, b
a, b, c
a, b, c, a
```

etc., but not any of the surrounding elements?

For a two element sequence comprising the entire list, this is straightforward, if a bit verbose:

```
MatchQ[#, {a | PatternSequence[a, b] .., a | PatternSequence[]}] & /@ 
 {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, a}, {a, b, a, b, a, b, a}}
(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

But, this does not work when the sequence is part of a bigger list, e.g.

```
Cases[
 {q, r, a, b, a, b, a, s, e, f, a}, 
 x : PatternSequence[a|(PatternSequence[a, b] ..), a | PatternSequence[]] :> {x}, 
 Infinity
]
(* {{a}, {a}, {a}, {a}} *)
```

Even reversing the initial element to `(PatternSequence[a, b] ..)|a` returns the same thing.

So, my questions are:

1. How can I write the pattern so it extracts parts of larger lists that may contain other elements?
2. How can I generalize the pattern to match against larger cyclically repeating sequences?

Comment: Partial success: `Cases[{{q, r, a, b, a, b, a, s, e, f, a}}, {y___, x : Longest@PatternSequence[(PatternSequence[a, b] ...), a | PatternSequence[]], z___} :> {x}]`.  I don't think `PatternSequence` matches a sub-`Sequence` by itself but needs to appear inside a `Head`.  I might be wrong, though.

Comment: I think @Michael is right: it generally doesn't seem to be possible to match any sequence on its own, only as part of a bigger expression.  `___` alone will only match a single element, but `{___}` will match a *list* with an arbitrary number of elements.  It is only the complete list that will match, not it's elements separately.  Example:  `ReplaceAll[Range[10], Longest[___Integer] -> x]`.  This can't replace the whole sequence of numbers in one go.  This can: `ReplaceAll[Range[10], z_[___Integer] :> z[x]]`.

Comment: So the key is to somehow also match on whatever contains that sequence.  What function do you want to use this in in practice?  `Cases`?  `Replace`?  `MatchQ`? Or a function definition?  It might work best in the last case.

Comment: @Szabolcs in general, I'm using `MatchQ`, but I would like it to be adaptable to both `Cases` and `Replace`. Usually, I'm working with lists, but I'd like this as general as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very interesting question.  I thought of a much plainer approach than the other responders but it proves to perform quite well.  I simply [`PadRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PadRight.html) the reference sequence to match the length of the test sequence.

*Update: limited extension to patterns within `ref` and timings updated for version 10.1.0.*

#### Functions

```
cycQ[ref_][test_] := test ~MatchQ~ PadRight[ref, Length @ test, ref]

cycpat[f_, r___] := p : PatternSequence[f, ___] /; cycQ[{f, r}][{p}] // Identity
```

`cycQ` tests one sequence against another:

```
cycQ[{1, 2, 3}] /@ {{}, {1}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1}, {2, 3}}
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True, False}
> ```

`cycpat` is the pattern-building function:

```
cycpat[1, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> p$ : PatternSequence[1, ___] /; cycQ[{1, 2, 3}][{p$}]
> ```

#### Sample applications

Sample data:

```
SeedRandom[1]
test = RandomInteger[{1, 3}, 20]
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2}
> ```

Finding the single longest sequence in the list:

```
test /. {___, x : Longest @ cycpat[1, 2, 3], ___} :> {x}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 1}
> ```

Finding all sequence fragments in a list, length 2 or greater:

```
ReplaceList[test, {___, x : cycpat[1, 2, 3] /; Length[{x}] > 1, ___} :> {x}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 2}}
> ```

#### Performance

rm -rf's `cyclicPatternMatchQ`, while certainly interesting, isn't fast enough to be widely applicable:

```
SeedRandom[1]
a = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 300];

a /. {___, x : Longest@cycpat[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ___} :> {x} // Timing

a /. {___, Longest@m__, ___} /; 
    cyclicPatternMatchQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}][{m}] :> {m}      // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.145, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
>
> {6.16204, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
> ```

belisarius's `form` function is much faster but still not as fast as `cycpat`:

```
form[w_List] := (* Note I removed the x and y patterns *)
 PatternSequence[Longest@Repeated[PatternSequence @@ w, {0, Infinity}], 
  Alternatives @@ 
    Table[Longest@Repeated[PatternSequence @@ w[[;; i]], {0, 1}], {i, Length[w], 1, -1}]]

SeedRandom[10]
big = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 1200];

big /. {___, q : Longest @ cycpat[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ___} :> {q}  // Timing
big /. {___, q : Longest @ form @ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, ___} :> {q} // Timing
```

> ```
> {6.18, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1}}
>
> {10.80, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1}}
> ```

It is worth noting however that (use of) `form` slows down semi-proportionately to the length of the sequence it is given, while `cycpat` does not:

```
big /. {___, q : Longest[cycpat @@ Range[50]], ___} :> {q} // Timing
big /. {___, q : Longest @ form @ Range[50], ___} :> {q}   // Timing
```

> ```
> {6.282, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
>
> {63.586, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
> ```

`cycpat` still seems rather slow for a list of only 1200 elements but I was unable to improve its performance.  Possibly a form of memoization would speed the highly repetitive application of `cycQ` without unacceptable memory consumption.

Comment: I am not sure if it is THAT slow. There should be about `Binomial[1200+2,2]` or 721801 sequences to try. `Do[f[i], {i, 1*^6}] // Timing` already takes the order of a second, so I doubt it can be improved more than an order of magnitude the most

Comment: +1, I wish I had thought of this. Very interesting.

Comment: @Rojo I suppose that for a standard pattern expression that may be correct.  I suspect that a stand-alone search would permit a more intelligent algorithm, but that is not what was requested.

Comment: @rcollyer Thank you.  Does your application *require* a pattern (that may be combined with other patterns, etc.) or do you simply want to search a list?  I suspect the latter can be much faster; for example if I know a priori that the longest match in `big` is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1` I can find its position in 0.00005 second.

Comment: I was just thinking there are cases where a pattern is absolutely necessary. I'll have to play with it a bit, and see.

Comment: I was just trying to use this like `MatchQ[list, _?(cycpat[p1, p2, ...])]` where the `pi` are patterns, and it keeps returning false. On the contrary, `MatchQ[list, _?(cycQ[{p1, p2, ...}])]` returns `True`. On the surface it looked like `_?(cycpat[...])` wasn't getting expanded, but adding an `UpValue` doesn't fix it. Not sure how to correct it to work with `MatchQ`, so I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: @rcollyer I wrote this only for a literal match, not patterns within the cycle itself.  Using `MatchQ` in place of `SameQ` should extend this to patterns that match a single element only, and I'll update my answer with that, but it's still far from general pattern handling!

Comment: `MatchQ` wasn't cutting it either, at least using `cycpat`.  But, I used the idea of building the pattern on the fly using it's length to get something that worked just fine, e.g. `cyclicPattern[p_List][test_List] /; Length@p <= Length@test := test~MatchQ~PadRight[{}, Length@test, p]` which is used like `MatchQ[{a,3,b}, _?(cyclicPattern[{_Symbol, _?NumericQ}])]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
findCyclicMatches[u_List, cycle_List] := Module[{form, x, y},
  form[w_List] := 
   PatternSequence[
    x : Longest@Repeated[PatternSequence @@ w, {0, Infinity}], 
    y : Alternatives @@ 
      Table[Longest@Repeated[PatternSequence @@ w[[;; i]], {0, 1}], {i, Length[w], 1, -1}]];

  Last@Reap@ NestWhileList[First@Cases[{#}, {r___, Longest@form@cycle, s___} :>
                                                    (Sow@{x, y}; {r, "Separator", s})] &, 
     u, 
    (Length@Last@{##} <= Length[{##}[[-2]]]) &, 2]
  ]
u = {a, b, c, kk, a, b, c, k, a, b, c, a, b, k, a, b, c, a};
findCyclicMatches[u, {a, b, c}]

(*
 {{{a, b, c, a, b}, {a, b, c, a}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {}}}
*)
```

Comment: I'll hold out for the clever way to generate the pattern, as I mainly wish to avoid having to write the thing out. But, +1.

Comment: @rcollyer Somewhat better now

Answer (score 5):

Here is a reasonable first implementation of a cyclical pattern matcher that behaves as described in the question. It takes an input cyclic list (single cycle) and a list that is to be tested:

```
ClearAll@cyclicPatternMatchQ
cyclicPatternMatchQ[cycList_][testList_] := MatchQ[cycList, 
    testList /. {Shortest[h___], (PatternSequence @@ cycList) ... , 
        Shortest[t___]} :> {h, t, ___}]
```

Here is a sample test case with results:

```
{#, cyclicPatternMatchQ[{a, b, c}]@#} & /@ {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, 
    c}, {a, b, c, a}, {a, b, c, a, b}, {x, y, z, p, q}, {d, a, b, c, 
    d}, {a, b, c, d, a}, {a, b, d, c}} // Grid
```

[image]

You can combine this with regular patterns to match cyclical patterns inside another list:

```
{d, a, b, c, a, e, f} /. 
    {h___, Longest@m__, t___} /; cyclicPatternMatchQ[{a, b, c}][{m}] :> {h, t}
(* {d, e, f} *)
```

Comment: +1. How would you make this amenable to using `PatternTest` instead of `Condition`?

Comment: @rcollyer Is there a reason you want to use `PatternTest`? `PatternTest` tests per element, whereas you want to test against the entire sequence, so I don't think it's the right tool.

Comment: More habit than anything else. But, I'm not sure you get that much savings with `Condition`, i.e. `{d, a, b, c, a, e, f} /. {h___, Longest@m__, t___} /; cyclicPatternMatchQ[{a, b, c}][Print[{m}]; {m}] :> {h, t}`. Using `Condition` is certainly easier, but I'm mostly just curious at this point.