# How to find the circulating fraction by pattern matching?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

#### Important note:

It's not hard to solve this problem, hence please explain how to use ***patterm matching*** instead of how to find the recurring period of a fraction.

---

We can easily extract real digits from a number, for example, $99/700$, using `RealDigits[99/700, 10, 24][[1]]` or so. The result is `{1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2, 8}`.

Now I would like to find out the recurring period which is `{1,4,2,8,5,7}`. This result is quite easy to get via this code: `RealDigits[99/700, 10][[1, -1]]`.

Well, I tried to find out this period myself and practice my programming ability with pattern matching when I found out I cannot easily do this job via this code:

```
RealDigits[99/700, 10, 
   24][[1]] /. {Shortest[pre___, 2], 
    Longest[Repeated[Shortest[r__, 3], {2, Infinity}], 4], 
    Shortest[inc___, 1]} /; 
   MatchQ[{r}, {inc, __}] -> {{pre}, {r}, {inc}}
```

I think this code could generate a proper result as:

1. Pattern matching will find out how to make the recurring range largest.
2. Then it will try to make the recurring body shortest.
3. After that it will ensure it leaves the least digits before the recurrence started.
4. At the next priority, it shall keep the left overs shortest.
5. Finally it will make sure that the left over shall be the starting part of the recurrence.

But in fact it gives out something like:

```
{{1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 8, 5}, {7, 1, 4, 2, 8, 5}, {7, 1, 4, 2, 8}}
```

Not that pleasant, still have place for improvements.

**How to solve this problem?** And furthermore, how can I throw away that `{2,Infinity}` in the `Repeated` and let the `Shortest` and `Longest` do the job? I think, theoretically, it's okay as `Longest` always find out the largest range while `Shortest` find out the smallest cycle. But I cannot think of a way to do this.

Comment: How would you plan to do with fractions like `123123123123123/10^24 + 1234/(10^28 - 1)`? I think your problem cannot be solved purely using `Shortest` and `Longest`, because you need to check whether the last part (the incomplete recurring period) belongs to the sequence you found.

Comment: Er, as I've said before, this is more like a toy problem. So I'm sure that this sequence has a recurring period after just a couple of digits. And, I think my code included the check about the left over of the sequence. I wrote `/;MatchQ[{r},{inc,__}]` to deal with it.

Comment: Somewhat related: [(43801)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43801/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem can be solved very efficiently using string patterns:

```
str = ToString[FromDigits@RealDigits[99/700, 10, 24][[1]]];

AbsoluteTiming[StringReplace[str,
  StartOfString ~~
  pre : Shortest[DigitCharacter ...] ~~
  Repeated[rep : Shortest[DigitCharacter ..], {2, Infinity}] ~~
  inc : DigitCharacter ... ~~
  EndOfString /;
    StringMatchQ[rep, inc ~~ __] :> pre <> "(" <> rep <> ")" <> inc]]
```

> ```
> {0.00488615, "14(142857)1428"}
> ```

Even million of digits takes lesser than 2 seconds to process:

```
str = ToString[FromDigits@RealDigits[99/700, 10, 1000000][[1]]];

AbsoluteTiming[StringReplace[str,
  StartOfString ~~
  pre : Shortest[DigitCharacter ...] ~~
  Repeated[rep : Shortest[DigitCharacter ..], {2, Infinity}] ~~
  inc : DigitCharacter ... ~~
  EndOfString /;
    StringMatchQ[rep, inc ~~ __] :> pre <> "(" <> rep <> ")" <> inc]]
```

> ```
> {1.27581, "14(142857)14"}
> ```

What is important, addition of arbitrary integer part doesn't alter the period even if this integer part contains recurring sequence of numbers:

```
str = ToString[FromDigits@RealDigits[141414141414141414 + 99/700, 10, 1000][[1]]];

AbsoluteTiming[StringReplace[str,
  StartOfString ~~
  pre : Shortest[DigitCharacter ...] ~~
  Repeated[rep : Shortest[DigitCharacter ..], {2, Infinity}] ~~
  inc : DigitCharacter ... ~~
  EndOfString /;
    StringMatchQ[rep, inc ~~ __] :> pre <> "(" <> rep <> ")" <> inc]]
```

> ```
> {0.049049, "14141414141414141414(142857)14"}
> ```

The crucial part here is `pre : Shortest[DigitCharacter ...]` which is converted internally to `RegularExpression["(\\d*?)"]` containing *lazy* quantifier `*?`. The algorithm behind this quantifier along with the `Condition` are what always gives us the *optimal* (not shifted) recurring period. By introducing pseudo-condition `(Print[{pre, rep, inc}]; True)` we can observe joint work of them both:

```
str = ToString[FromDigits@RealDigits[14 + 99/700, 10, 24][[1]]];

StringReplace[str,
  StartOfString ~~
  pre : Shortest[DigitCharacter ...] ~~
  Repeated[rep : Shortest[DigitCharacter ..], {2, Infinity}] ~~
  inc : DigitCharacter ... ~~
  EndOfString /;
    (Print[{pre, rep, inc}]; True) && StringMatchQ[rep, inc ~~ __] :> 
      pre <> "(" <> rep <> ")" <> inc];
```

> {, 14, 285714285714285714}
>
> {, 14, 14285714285714285714}
>
> {1, 41, 4285714285714285714}
>
> {14, 14, 285714285714285714}
>
> {1414, 142857, 14}

From the above we can clearly see how the lazy quantifier `*?` works and what is the role of the `Condition` in rejecting inappropriate matches.

Note that the above condition `StringMatchQ[rep, inc ~~ __]` isn't sufficiently strict to provide the optimal period without the optimal searching algorithm. For example if we reverse the string and change the condition correspondingly, we get shifted period because now the leading pattern is `inc : DigitCharacter ...` and hence the search is performed in wrong order:

```
str = ToString[FromDigits@RealDigits[99/700, 10, 24][[1]]];

StringReplace[StringReverse@str,
  StartOfString ~~
  inc : DigitCharacter ... ~~
  Repeated[rep : Shortest[DigitCharacter ..], {2, Infinity}] ~~
  pre : Shortest[DigitCharacter ...] ~~
  EndOfString /;
    (Print[StringReverse /@ {pre, rep, inc}]; True) && StringMatchQ[rep, __ ~~ inc] :> 
      inc <> ")" <> rep <> "(" <> pre] // StringReverse;
```

> {, 14, 28571428571428571428}
>
> {14, 142857, 1428571428}
>
> {141, 428571, 428571428}
>
> {1414, 285714, 28571428}
>
> {14142, 857142, 8571428}
>
> {141428, 571428, 571428}
>
> {1414285, 714285, 71428}
>
> ```
> "1414285(714285)71428"
> ```

With a more rigorous condition `StringMatchQ[rep, __ ~~ inc] && UnsameQ @@ StringTake[{pre, rep}, UpTo[1]]` we get the optimal result despite the suboptimal searching algorithm:

```
StringReplace[StringReverse@str,
  StartOfString ~~
  inc : DigitCharacter ... ~~
  Repeated[rep : Shortest[DigitCharacter ..], {2, Infinity}] ~~
  pre : Shortest[DigitCharacter ...] ~~
  EndOfString /;
    StringMatchQ[rep, __ ~~ inc] && UnsameQ @@ StringTake[{pre, rep}, UpTo[1]] :> 
      inc <> ")" <> rep <> "(" <> pre] // StringReverse
```

> ```
> "14(142857)1428"
> ```

It is worth to note that [Mr.Wizard's elegant solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121853/280) via the native *Mathematica*'s patterns also can't process correctly the list in the reverse direction. In the following I essentially have changed only the condition in order to allow it to match the reversed list:

```
Reverse[RealDigits[99/700, 10, 24][[1]]] /. 
  {inc___, Repeated[rep__, {2, Infinity}], pre___} /; 
    MatchQ[{rep}, {__, inc}] :> Reverse /@ {{pre}, {rep}, {inc}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2, 8}, {5, 7, 1, 4, 2, 8}, {}}
> ```

But it can be cured easily by wrapping `pre___` with `Shortest`:

```
Reverse[RealDigits[99/700, 10, 24][[1]]] /. 
  {inc___, Repeated[rep__, {2, Infinity}], Shortest@pre___} /; 
   MatchQ[{rep}, {__, inc}] :> Reverse /@ {{pre}, {rep}, {inc}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 4}, {1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7}, {1, 4, 2, 8}}
> ```

This improved solution also works well with the original list:

```
RealDigits[99/700, 10, 24][[1]] /. 
  {Shortest@pre___, Repeated[rep__, {2, Infinity}], inc___} /; 
    MatchQ[{rep}, {inc, __}] :> {{pre}, {rep}, {inc}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 4}, {1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7}, {1, 4, 2, 8}}
> ```

Note that there is no way to cure the string pattern in order to allow it to process the string in the reverse direction the same way as in the forward direction. This illustrates the fundamental [difference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108399/280) between string patterns (based on regular expressions) and native *Mathematica*'s patterns. Although one should understand that (at least in the general case) the latter also work differently depending on the direction as can be seen from the following excerpt from the Documentation and proven using `ReplaceList` (as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121856/280)):

> If several `Shortest` objects occur in the same expression, those that
>   appear first are given higher priority to match shortest sequences.

Comment: Nice circumvention of the OP's opening paragraph.  This is pattern-matching after all. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm rather surprised that *Mathematica*'s pattern matcher works so slowly in this case. Probably it isn't designed/optimized for such purposes at all?

Comment: There are lots of cases where it is abysmally slow and I believe the explanation is the engine handling every test independently to allow for fringe cases like stateful conditions, which I just remarked upon today [(121852)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121852/121).  A much older post: [(8522876)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8522876/)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This topic seems to be very subtle and little known. Admittedly I still don't fully understand what you mean by "stateful conditions" available with the *Mathematica*'s patterns and not available with the string patterns (both support `Condition` after all!). Could you elaborate it?

Comment: I am referring to this: [(8485700)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8485700/)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I missed that answer. But my point remains: with string patterns we have mutable conditions as well as with the usual patterns. It is easy to demonstrate with the `test3` function from the [Leonid's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8485700/590388): try `StringMatchQ["12345", Shortest[x__?test3] ~~ y__]` and you get the same as with `MatchQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {x__?test3, y__}]` (with fresh `flag`). I mean I still do not understand why the usual patterns must be so much slower than the string patterns: the mutability (stateful nature) of the conditions does not convince me.

Comment: You probably have a very good point (you usually do after all) and I'll take a look at that later, but I am too tired to consider it now.  I know that there are [other differences](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108399/121) and I imagine that other pattern matching engines (including the one used for strings in *Mathematica*) may be simply better optimized as well.

Comment: Yes, as @Wizard have said, this is a great answere for an opening question! And, Thanks for your inspiring discussion! I viewed links related and links in links, truely corrected a lot of misunderstanding of the pattern matching mechanism accumulated through years......

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have extended my answer substantially. You can be interested in the added considerations.

Comment: Thank you.  Very interesting stuff.  I would +1 again if I could.

Answer (score 9):

This is an extended comment, and should give an answer to your first question.

If you are fine with your current code style, I did find a setting of your priority of `Shortest` and `Longest` that gives you the expected result. So here they are:

```
RealDigits[99/700, 10, 24][[1]]/.{Shortest[pre___, 3], 
 Longest[Repeated[Shortest[rep__, 1], {2, Infinity}]], 
 Shortest[inc___, 2]} /; MatchQ[{rep}, {inc, __}] :> {{pre}, {rep}, {inc}}
```

In my experiments, I found that the priority of `Shortest` and `Longest` is not related, so the setting for `Longest` can be removed. If you are curious why I have this conclusion, here is the list of "full" parameters I found:

```
{{3, 1, 4, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 2, 1, 3}}
```

The third argument is for `Longest`, and clearly its priority does not matter.

Also, I think `{2, Infinity}` in your `Repeat` can't be omitted, otherwise the program tends to regard the whole sequence as the recurring period.

I didn't explore further into this problem or fully tested the settings, so I am not sure how well it can generalize.

Comment: So mainly you ommited the priority setting of Longest? but what priority will be get if there's no priority setting? 0?

Comment: @Wjx Please see my edit.

Comment: and, I can see from your profile that you're a Chinese as well? will you mind adding my wechat?

Comment: but that's wierd, I suppose there'll be some situations where we need to specify the priority of both Shortest and Longest?

Comment: @Wjx Of course. I updated my email in my profile, so we can exchange other more private contact via email. Regarding your question, I didn't think of a case that would cause conflict yet.

Comment: yep, in this case there'll be no conflict between them, but as it's a question more about pattern matching than this specific problem, I think this can be further discussed~

Comment: @Wjx yeah, I don't really understand how they would interfere with each other since they look pretty much like blackboxes. Could be a good question to ask.

Comment: Well, yes! a new and more directed question will help~ thanks! also, check your email box~

Answer (score 4):

*Update:* I managed to confuse myself with various combinations of `Shortest` and `Longest`.  The plainest form of all seems to work just fine on my system (*Mathematica* 10.1 under Windows):

```
RealDigits[99/700, 10, 24][[1]] /.
  {pre___, Repeated[rep__, {2, Infinity}], inc___} /; 
    MatchQ[{rep}, {inc, __}] :> {{pre}, {rep}, {inc}} // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {7.496, {{1, 4}, {1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7}, {1, 4, 2, 8}}}
> ```

happy fish's code by comparison:

```
RealDigits[99/700, 10, 24][[1]] /. {Shortest[pre___, 3], 
  Longest[Repeated[Shortest[rep__, 1], {2, Infinity}]], Shortest[inc___, 2]} /; 
    MatchQ[{rep}, {inc, __}] :> {{pre}, {rep}, {inc}} // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {8.5745, {{1, 4}, {1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7}, {1, 4, 2, 8}}}
> ```

Comment: though I have enjoyed looking at all these answers, Mma/WL (whichever your preferred) `RealDigits[99/700]`  reports the recurring pattern.

Comment: @ubpdqn I am fairly certain that is *not* what the question is about however, but rather it was simply used as an arbitrary example for the actual question about pattern matching.

Comment: ok I guess I am suggesting that the algorithm used in the case of argument in integers is very efficient (noting the times in your  post). I am sorry for the misinterpretation...after dinner I might think about it...

Comment: I did put my 2 cents worth in...I am off to dinner. I apologize for any misunderstanding and I have learned a lot from provided answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this is about pattern matching. I merely point out that Mathematica returns the desired recurring pattern with exact fractions.

I post this 'emulation' of long division as matching the same 'number' using `NestWhileList` and checking against all. This is how I would work the pattern in my head as a child. Sadly, my facility in this regard has significantly waned.

```
fun[n_, d_] :=
 Module[{lst = 
    NestWhileList[QuotientRemainder[10 #[[2]], d] &, 
     QuotientRemainder[n, d], UnsameQ, All], p},
  p = Position[lst, lst[[-1]]][[1, 1]];
  {lst[[1 ;; p - 1, 1]], lst[[p ;; -2, 1]]}
  ]
```

Tests:

```
test = {1/7, 1/23, 99/700, 1/17, 23/29};
Grid[{#, RealDigits[#], fun[Numerator@#, Denominator@#]} & /@ test, 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]